# Setting Windows Application parent container to a Java application

Tags: java, windows, embed, parent

I was wondering if there is a way to embed a windows application like photoshop inside a java application?  More specifically I would like to set the parent container of the windows application to a JPanel or JFrame.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think Swing/AWT cannot do this without a (guest program specific) [JNI](http://nothome.com/IECanvas/).

Check out [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834771/java-swt-how-to-receive-mouse-events-from-an-embedded-window).

Answer (score -1):

Look into [JInternalFrames](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but JInternalFrames is more for internal java panes, not for embedding windows applications.

Comment: Looking at the docs for JInternalFrames, it does not seem apparent how I would embed a Windows application like Word, Photoshop, or Firefox.  Can you explain a little more in your post how you did it?